# Multiple users working on one CSV file

Tags: csv, vb6

I am working with CSV file in my project. Multiple users can open and read+write the CSV file through ADODB connection. But I am facing a problem, when multiple users like more than 10 users work on it then application stop working, is there any limit to read a file by multiple users?
and when multiple users work on it it becomes slow to read+write the data from CSV files.

Could you please help me to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any concurrency control mechanism for text files besides locking entire files.  The problem is that text files aren't practical to update in-place: the only way to make changes is to rewrite the entire file.  Yes, byte ranges can be locked but this isn't a practical strategy for a text file.

It sounds like you are using either the Jet Text IISAM or a hoary old ODBC Text Driver.  These have never supported shared use and offer no concurrency control besides whole-file locking.

Opening read-only might offer better shared use of files not being modified of course.

I can't think of any "limit" as you speculate.  More likely you are just having more locked file collisions when you have more clients.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit imposed by Windows on the number of concurrent connections.
This varies per windows version, limit for Windows XP is 10 and the limit for Windows 7 is 20. (simultaneous connections for file/print sharing, IIS, ICS and telephony services)

The limits are considerably higher for Windows Server versions